Equality of cycle index polynomial does not imply isomorphism, of groups
I'm working on a counter-example of the following proposition: equality of the cycle index polynomials of two groups imply that those groups are isomorphic. This comes from problem 12 of Stanley's Algebraic Combinatorics (2nd edition). I'm told that there exist a nonabelian group $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_3^2 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3$ of order 27 such that $x^3 = 1$ for every $x \in G$. I'm trying to prove that $Z_G = Z_H$ (equality of the cycle index polynomials) for some non-isomorphic group of order $27$. I think $H = \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ provided that we also have $x^3 = 1$ for every $x \in H$. This last condition imply that, as subgroups of $S_{27}$, every element in $G$ and $H$ is the product of $3$-cycles. I don't know how to prove that there existe equal number of elements with $k$ $3$-cycles and $m$ $1$-cycles in $G$ and $H$ for every $k, m \in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ with $m + 3k = 27$.
